# How to use string variable in different event?

Tags: c#, string, private, void

I'd like to know how to call/use a string from another method.

```
public partial class PPAP_Edit : Form
    {
    string Main_dir { get; set; }
    string Sub_dir { get; set; }
    string targetPath { get; set; }
```

...etc I don't want to copy all

```
private void button_browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (od.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                Main_dir = @"C:\Users\h109536\Documents\PPAP\";
                Sub_dir = text_PSW_ID.Text + "_" + text_Partnumber.Text + "_" + text_Partrev.Text + @"\";
                targetPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Main_dir, Sub_dir);
                {
                    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
                    {
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
                        MessageBox.Show("Folder has been created!");
                    }
                    foreach (string fileName in od.FileNames)

                        System.IO.File.Copy(fileName, targetPath + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName), true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }
                    }
private void button_open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Folder is not added to the database!");
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", Main_dir);                
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", Main_dir + Sub_dir);
        }                       
    }
```

I am reffering to the ***Main_dir***, ***Sub_dir*** and ***targetPath*** strings but the open button method doesn't work until I click the browse button.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: "open button method doesn't work until I click the browse button" -- How do you propose to open a folder if `Main_dir`, `targetPath`, and `Sub_dir` have not yet  been defined through the "browse" button?

Comment: Correct me If I am wrong but I think it shouldn't define through the openFiledialog. Main_dir is already defined as @"C:\ also the sub_dir from the text boxies

Comment: If I put the whole code into the open button event than browser method stop working.

Comment: You're declaring `Main_dir`, `Sub_dir`, and `targetPath` in your class, but the only place you are assigning a value to them is in your browse button click handler.  So in order for `button_open_Click` to be able to use them, you need to click browse first.  If you want to click open without clicking browse, then you'll need to assign these variables somewhere else before open is clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the default for your main directory from the form's constructor. It'll then be available to any methods within the form. The sub and target path are just functions, and can be put in the properties getter methods.

```
public partial class PPAP_Edit : Form 
{
    // set this from constructor
    public string MainDir { get; set; }

    // can't set this in constructor as it requires access to form controls, but can just use the getter
    public string SubDir
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return text_PSW_ID.Text + "_" + text_Partnumber.Text + "_" + text_Partrev.Text + @"\"; 
        } 
    }

    // again just use the getter
    public string TargetPath 
    {
        get 
        {
            return Path.Combine(MainDir, SubDir);
        }
    }

    // set defaults in constructor 
    public PPAP_Edit()
    {
        MainDir = @"C:\Users\h109536\Documents\PPAP\";
    }
}
```

Comment: Working perfectly! Thanks a lot!